# What are these unexpected databases in my MySQL AWS RDS instance?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

On my AWS RDS MySQL instance I have some databases I didn't explicitly create there (and have never seen on my local MySQL databases, or on other hosted databases I've worked with) and wonder what they are (and what I can do about them):

```
information_schema
mysql
performance_schema    
innodb
```

The first three are filled with data that I don't understand (and are listed separately in my MySQL tools; e.g. I have no ability to control privileges for them separately), while the last is empty. Can I delete the `innodb`? What are the others (I assume I should leave them alone)?

---

Forgive what may turn out to be a naive MySQL or AWS question; I'm fairly new to both.

Comment: They're built-in databases in MySQL, and you should leave them alone. They're required for basically EVERYTHING mysql does.

Comment: And `innodb` as well? Do I have these on my local MySQL installation and just not see them for some reason?

Comment: dunno about innodb, that's a new one, but the other ones are core databases. `mysql` contains all kinds of configuration info, and especially contains the user account info. information_schema is a virtual db that lets you query stuff about OTHER dbs, and the performance_shema lets you view internal performance info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are all normal.

Every MySQL installation has the `mysql` and `information_schema` databases.  If you can't see them, then either you either don't have permission to see them, or whatever you're using to connect to the MySQL server is hiding them from you.  Most newer MySQL installations also have `performance_schema`.

The `innodb` database on RDS isn't really a database, but it shows up in the list because of the way the design of RDS interacts with MySQL server's internal concept that each directory inside that datadir is assumed to be a database.  Files that InnoDB uses internally are stored there, even though the "database" itself appears to be empty.  Just disregard it.

The `mysql` database contains tables used internally by MySQL, including the grant tables and time zone tables, and some DBA tools in the form of stored procedures that are specific to RDS, which are required due to the restricted access that even the administrator account has to an RDS instance, when compared to a standalone MySQL server.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-schema.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/performance-schema.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.MySQL.CommonDBATasks.html